# Import yoast SEO headers from Wordpress into gatsby site

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, gatsby, yoast, react-helmet

I have a wordpress website, and I want to migrate it to Gatsby. I have found a lot of documentation and I now have a working site in Gatsby. But there is something I haven't been able to do: Import the meta tags generated by yoast into Gatsby.

I add yoast_head to the graphql query and I have access to the meta tags and the title in a string, but I don't know how to put it into the header of the page

I tried:

```
<Helmet dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yoastHead }} />
```

But that did not work

If I do

```
<div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: yoastHead }} />
```

I can render all the meta tags on the body of the page, but I want them to be added inside `<head></head>`

Answer (score 3):

I found the way:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-html-parser

```
import ReactHtmlParser from 'react-html-parser'

...

      <Helmet>
        { ReactHtmlParser(yoastHead) }
      </Helmet
...
```

Comment: I'd be careful with this approach if you don't trust the author of this (e.g. if you have guest authors or include user-submitted information in these tags) since `react-html-parser` doesn't sanitize the input (i.e. someone could readily use JavaScript or malicious markup in it).

Comment: I understand, but I am the only author